# Shopping Cart web service don't add products with tax include in Prestashop

Tags: web-services, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem adding a cart with web service in prestashop (add), because when save the products, these don't insert with the tax assigned.

Example: the X product cost is 522 tax include(tax 16%), but prestashop register is 450.

HAS A PROBLEM THE SERVICE?

This is the service information receive:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <cart>
   <id_address_delivery format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_address_invoice format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_currency required="true" format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_customer format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_guest format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_lang required="true" format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_shop_group format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_shop format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <id_carrier format="isUnsignedId"/>
   <recyclable format="isBool"/>
   <gift format="isBool"/>
   <gift_message format="isMessage"/>
   <mobile_theme format="isBool"/>
   <delivery_option/>
   <secure_key maxSize="32"/>
   <allow_seperated_package format="isBool"/>
   <date_add format="isDateFormat"/>
   <date_upd format="isDateFormat"/>
   <associations>
      <cart_rows virtual_entity="true" node_type="cart_row">
         <cart_row>
            <id_product xlink:href="http://www.mimetics.com.co/SiloWeb/prestashop/api/products/" required="true"/>
            <id_product_attribute xlink:href="http://www.mimetics.com.co/SiloWeb/prestashop/api/combinations/" required="true"/>
            <id_address_delivery xlink:href="http://www.mimetics.com.co/SiloWeb/prestashop/api/addresses/" required="true"/>
            <quantity required="true"/>
         </cart_row>
      </cart_rows>
   </associations>
</cart>
</prestashop>
```

But any attribute lets add tax.

need your help, Thanks everybody.

PD: Sorry for my bad English.